# How to validate that a ajax server-calculated result matches the UI actions of a user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, hash

I have a form where the user can select a range of values by checking checkboxes.
There are two lists of checkboxes, one is using integers as values, and the other is using strings.

The issue is that i need to present the user with some calculated result based on the values they picked in the checkboxes.
This calculation can be quite slow, anywhere from 2 to 20 seconds.

Currently the ajax request to calculate the value executes just as the user checks any checkboxes. But this results in a request for every checkbox they click. And the calculated result returned on each request sometimes arrive in the wrong order, which means that the slowest / last arriving response is the one being presented to the user.

I't seems I have to validate the response to the values selected by the user, to only display a result if it matches the selected checkboxes.
I would think a hash value would be the best fix to this issue. But i had a bit of trouble locating a suitable hash function with implemtations in C# and javascript.

I know i could just return the user actions when returning the results, but i would still have to compare all the values, and the amount of values can be quite large.

Optimal i would like to generate a hash of the selected values on the server, and then generate a hash of the current selected values on the client when the result is returned, and then comparing the two would indicate if the result matches the selected values.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Backend/GetCalculatedResult',
  data: { CheckedIntegers: checkedIntegers, CheckedStrings: checkedStrings },
  success: function(data) {
        if(ResultMatchesSelection(data.SelectionHash)) {
            DisplayResult(data.Result);
        }
  },
  dataType: "json",
});

function ResultMatchesSelection(hash)
{
    var selectionHash = .. generate hash from selected items;
    return hash == selectionHash;
}
```

I have made a partial fix to this issue, by executing the ajax request 1 second after the last user action. So that if the user checks 5 checkboxes in sequence, with less than one second between each, the request will only execute once, and not 5 times.

I would really like a combination of the two.

Do you have a idea to how i can do this hashing on both server and client side?
Or if you have an idea to how this could be solved in another way, please do speak your mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hashing selected values and checking them back with the ajax result, you could declare a global variable, say `requestNo`, in jQuery and send that variable value with each ajax call (increment `requestNo` value for every ajax request).

While you return ajax response, instead of hashed value, return the `requestNo` value which you received with ajax request. In the client side check if the `requestNo` in ajax response is same as current `requestNo` value and display results if they are same.

Comment: This is not the solution I used, but this seems like a great way to solve it. See my answer for the solution i used.

Answer (score 1):

Try using visual indicator (loading image) to the user that calculation is still happening in the server.
if you are using Ajax.ActionLink ,use this :[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.loadingelementid(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.loadingelementid%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Also there are many ways to do that using jQuery.jQuery has ajax methods  :
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp
,so you can use ajaxStart and ajaxStop/ajaxComplete , to show and hide your loading image.

Comment: Some kind of visual loading indicator is extremely important, that feeling when it seems nothing is happening is just terrible, and people hate it. But adding a small picture will make them get soo much more patient.

Comment: That's right,but i think that loading image will not hide until the last request's response is returned,so you don't need to check any value or using hashing method to make sure that the result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I took another route, which seems to solve the issue just fine.
Instead of checking values, i save the last ajax request, and every time an action occurs, it checks if the last request is still loading, and if it is, it is aborted, and the new request is sent.

If, as i belive it will, make sure that two request cannot be pending at the same time, this should solve the issue just fine :)